# Harrowing missing $ inserted error with 'case'

Tags: math-mode

I am a complete newbie to LaTeX. I am having a harrowing time with the missing `$` error.
I have the following code:

```
\begin{cases}
soil(i, j) if min(soil(i, l)) $\geq$ 0\\ 
$k \notin nodes$ \\
soil(i, j) - min(soil(i, l)) else \\
$k\notin nodes$ 
\end{cases}
```

which seems to be generating the missing `$` error.
I thought maybe the `$` sign was a problem. But despite removing that I got the same error.
Could you please let me know what is the problem?

P.S. I apologize if this has been asked before, but I couldn't seem to find the solution.

Comment: `cases` is a math block. Don't use `$` inside it. Use `\text{}` for text inside it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a proper [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Make sure you have put the `cases` environment within math mode (such as inside a `displaymath` environment), and, as already mentioned, remove the `$` from within `cases`.

Answer (score 4):

I could not guess the intended layout, probably not this, but this runs without error and should get you started

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator\soil{soil}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{cases}
\soil(i, j) &\text{if }\min(\soil(i, l)) \geq 0\\ 
k \notin \mathrm{nodes} \\
\soil(i, j) - \min(\soil(i, l))&\text{ else} \\
k\notin \mathrm{nodes}
\end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```